# How do you get the degree of the canonical class of a divisor from the adjunction formula?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a surface and $D$ a divisor on $X$ how do you get to $\deg K_D=(K_X+D)\cdot D$ from the adjunction formula $K_D=(K_X+D)_{|D}$?

Comment: Unless you are on a surface and thus $D$ is a curve, degree of $K_D$ does not make without fixing an ample bundle.

Comment: @Mohan Indeed, $X$ is a surface.

Comment: In this case, $D$ is a curve (presumably projective, otherwise degree is meaningless and degree of a line bundle makes sense and they are the same line bundle on a curve.